# automating twitter card on a dynamic web page

Tags: twitter-card

I have read all the posts with search term "twitter card" 
I am not an expert in coding, just trying my hand 
at automating twitter card 
so any help is much much appreciated

i added this to product.php

```
    <?php include"header2.php" ; ?>

    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta name="twitter:title" value="<?php echo $title ?>" >
    <meta name="twitter:description" value="<?php echo $description ?>" >
```

where header2.php is

```
    <?php 
    echo "<meta name='description' content='$description' />"; 
    echo "<meta name='title' content='$title' />"; 
    ?>
```

this is the dynamically pulled page

```
    www.celebrationinvites.com/boho_wild_roses_bridal_shower_invitations_zazzle_invitation2-256484831955683674.html
```

this is the basic page

```
    www.celebrationinvites.com/product.php
```

the validator 
        https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

shows this error4

INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  8 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found
ERROR: Invalid value (message: Field description failed to validate because: text expects tag property, but not found in Map().)

I know I am messing up the automation code, googled a lot, just don't know what I need to fix please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your meta description and meta title are written wrong. In order to be valid opengraph you need to use the `property` attribute not the `name` attribute. So in order to fix this all you need to do is change header2.php to...

```
<?php 
echo "<meta property='og:description' content='$description' />"; 
echo "<meta property='og:title' content='$title' />"; 
?>
```

**Update #1**
A quick check of your site shows that the `og:title`, `twitter:title`, `og:description`, and `twitter:description` tags are empty. These must contain the appropriate text and can't be blank. You are also missing the `twitter:site` and `twitter:creator` tags which will cause a validator problem next and will need to be added as they are required.

What you effectively need in your head section is a block that looks like this...

```
<meta property='og:description' content='<?php echo($description) ?>' />
<meta property='og:title' content='<?php echo($title) ?>' />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" value="<?php echo($title) ?>" >
<meta name="twitter:description" value="<?php echo($description) ?>" >
<meta name="twitter:site" value="Site Name" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" value="<?php echo($author) ?>" />
```

The `twitter:site` meta tag should be manually defined as it remains the same across all pages (It is just the name of your site). The creator meta tag can be either manually defined as the site name as well if you want all content to show as being authored by the site and not a specific user or you can dynamically echo it out by specifying the `$author` PHP variable to allow you to specify the actual author of the articles.

NB: The code you supplied was missing the `twitter:site` and `twitter:creator` meta tags which are required by Twitter.

Comment: umm still getting this error in validator Log
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  10 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found
ERROR: Required meta tag missing (twitter:text:description)
ERROR: Required meta tag missing (twitter:text:title)

Comment: I have rechecked your site and tested it with a local copy and have updated my answer based on my testing of your code. The update contains the block you will need to have in your head section to make it work. I have tested this on my server and it has worked to get a card displaying. If you want to have additional data added you will just need to check the Twitter meta guide on what additional meta tags to display.

Comment: that's the whole point ! if i add this block ,of course it will work but i will have to manually put title description,..,image e.t.c in validator it shows some text description here and what i am wanting as my original question to automatically pull title and description for the page to show "the title of the page" and not "page title" to show "the description of the product" and not "some description here" i want to auto pull title and description this is why i was trying to use og and echo ..e.t.c

Comment: Okay from your comment you seem to be saying that you have the page title and page description loaded as PHP variables which you want to use to populate the meta tags. In line with this I have updated my code block in my answer to add the PHP echo statements to pull the title and description variables and echo them into the right spots. One thing I did note through my tests was that you didn't have the twitter:site and twitter:creator meta tags defined in the sample code you provided and they are needed so I have added them to my code block.

Comment: They can be dynamically generated by adding an echo statement to them if you want or can be manually defined by hand coding in the values into the meta tags. How you break them up across your PHP files is up to you, as long as all the meta tags in the example I have given to you appear in the page head block somewhere, order doesn't matter, then it will work.

Comment: same errors  :( INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  12 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found
ERROR: Required meta tag missing (twitter:text:description)
ERROR: Required meta tag missing (twitter:text:title)

Comment: I have just checked your life site and the title and description meta tags are not been filled by your echo statements. It would appear that either `$title`, $description`, and `$author` are not being defined in your code or if they are being defined then they are being defined as blank. These tags can not be empty, they must have text in order to pass validation.

Comment: I am hoping somewhere n this "product.php" you can see how title is auto pulled from the feed as product.php is a blank page with no title or image or description or price and this code pulls it for the page as soon as a product is clicked..so maybe what to put in echo code is somewhere here in the following code?.... continued in next comment

Comment: here is the code
 <meta name="description" content="<?=$metaDescription?>" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$metaKeywords?>" />
 <title><?=$title?> on <?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?></title>


 <div class="titleBar">
  <h1 class="h1Title"><?=$title?></h1>
 </div>

<div class="descriptionShell"><?=$description?></div>

Comment: Sorry just to clarify here do you actually have the code already done to populate the `$title` and `$description` variables on your page or are you trying to define them based on data parsed from another page as this seems to be jumping back and forth between issues at the moment. As for your comment the only thing that your code shows is that you have a `$title` and `$description` variable defined which are then used in `header2.php` and `product.php` in order to echo the appropriate data into the title and description meta tags. How they are defined is unknown.

Comment: If you already have the `$title` and `$description` variables defined through some previous unseen code then I am struggling to see where the issue is coming from as I have already stated that the `twitter:creator` meta tag can be statically defined in your HTML without needing to assign a variable for it in which case the code will take your existing two variables and use them to complete the meta data block needed to successfully enable twitter cards on your pages.

Comment: OMG it is working now! all I needed was to place the block code you sent me after the $title was pulled at the product.php so I added it before /body tag! however it is not pulling image as yet! :) just the title description and link! but the twitter card validated!!! so now to figure why not the image!

Comment: AND THE IMAGE IS ALSO WORKING NOW! woohoo!

Comment: Fantastic thats good news.

Comment: if you can please take a look on this issue of resizing the twitter card image :) http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103560/auto-resizing-twitter-card-image-to-fit-twitter-timeline

Comment: Answered for you.