# auto resizing twitter card image to fit twitter timeline

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

my code looks like this

```
    <meta property='og:description' content='<?php echo($description) ?>' />
    <meta property='og:title' content='<?php echo($title) ?>' />
    <meta property='og:image' content='<?php echo($imageSrc) ?>' />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content= "280" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content= "150" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta name="twitter:title" value="<?php echo($title) ?>" >
    <meta name="twitter:description" value="<?php echo($description) ?>" >
    <meta name="twitter:site" value="Wedding Paper Love" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" value="<?php echo($author) ?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" value=""<?php echo($imageSrc) ?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:image:width" value= "280" />
    <meta name="twitter:image:height" value= "150" />
```

twitter card is validating but the image shows like this on timeline
[image]

how can I make the twitter card image to show like this

[image]

any leads?
thanks
Maria

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this won't be able to be done. The `twitter:image:width` and `twitter:image:height` meta tags where supported for the Twitter PhotoCard only however that was depreciated on 3rd July 2015. The summary card with large image (which is what you are using) does not support changing the size of the provided image. Based on Twitter documentation the image linked to in the meta tag should be at least 280px in width and 150px in height. If you wish to maintain the aspect ratio then you would need to increase the height of the image (as in the source image by scaling it up) to the point that the width scales up to 280px. There does not appear to be anyway to change this behaviour with Twitter and I suspect that it is more to do with CSS rules widening the image without adjusting the corresponding height to maintain the aspect ratio.

You will need to remove the height and width meta tags as these are not supported and use larger images.

As a side note there is a hard limit that the image must be less than 1MB in size so even you scale it up to a larger size you have to make sure that the final file size remains below 1MB.

Comment: In order to echo out the image URL with PHP the `$imageSrc` variable has to be defined in your code previously. A check of the echo statement in your comment shows that it is written exactly how it needs to be written, now all you have to do is go to where you define the `$description` and `$title` PHP variables (from your previous question) and define the image URL variable there based on the same data source you are using for the articles.

Comment: I can't help you with the view padding part as it is not documented in the Twitter API. I would however recommend not relying on it as not being documented it will probably be a bug which could be closed out in a later version of the API.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll keep on working on it, there must be some workaround I am missing :) thx for all your help though :)

Comment: ok I have found what needs to be fixed but don;t know how since you know $imgSrc is auto pulling the image say this one
https://rlv.zcache.com/boho_chic_floral_bridal_shower_invitations-r92fbd138481a43f3917c9da5338e9a96_zkrqs_367.jpg?rlvnet=1&bg=0xFFFFFF
now if I want to replace _367.jpg to _150.jpg but only in twitter card result here
<meta name="twitter:image" value=""<?php echo($imageSrc) ?>" />
<meta property='og:image' content='<?php echo($imageSrc) ?>' />
is this even possible?

Comment: this is not working <meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo($imageSrc) ?>height='150' width='280' " />

Comment: So you want your code to change the image from _367 to _150 but only for the twitter card?

Comment: yes this is exactly what I want :)

Comment: You can achieve this by using `<meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo(str_replace("367.jpg", "150.jpg, $imageSrc)) ?>" />`

What this does is searches the `$imageSrc` variable for any instance of `367.jpg` and replaces it with `150.jpg`. The `str_replace` function returns the ammended string with the changes in it so by wrapping it in an echo statement the code will echo out the changed string with no problem. You can find out more on the `str_replace` function at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: ok the syntax did work there was " missing after 150.jpg but now twitter card is not rendering any image at all! :(
though the validator says

INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  16 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found
INFO:  Card loaded successfully

but there is no image :(

Comment: I aso tried adding this
<meta property='og:image' content='<?php echo(str_replace("367.jpg", "150.jpg", $imageSrc)) ?>' /> or this 

<meta property='og:image' content='<?php echo(str_replace('367.jpg', '150.jpg', $imageSrc)) ?>' />

Comment: the code is rendering fine as the page source shows

<meta property='og:image' content='https://rlv.zcache.com/boho_wild_roses_bridal_shower_invitations-r14f129f7d6a14a24ab74084dea94374b_6gdcb_150.jpg?rlvnet=1&amp;bg=0xFFFFFF' />



<meta name="twitter:creator" value="" />
<meta name="twitter:image" value="https://rlv.zcache.com/boho_wild_roses_bridal_shower_invitations-r14f129f7d6a14a24ab74084dea94374b_6gdcb_150.jpg?rlvnet=1&amp;bg=0xFFFFFF" />

just the validator is showing no image even after validating the code!

Comment: Scale OMG! do you think this is where padding comes into play? twitter card needs ratio of 2:1 for the image to display if it is going to be of maximum height 150px so zazzle added white space to width to make the ratio 2:1 in respect to 150px? like make width (280px) by adding padding.....

Comment: right now it is 150x150 so need to add 130px on sides like 65px on both sides to increase the width to 280px! and then I am sure it will work! if only that is possible! hahaha !

Comment: so apparently this should work but how would we substitute in our code?

To  get an image with exact dimensions (i.e. add whitespace) use with borderImage:  
$desired_width = 1000;
$desired_height = 1000;

$image->scaleImage($desired_width,$desired_height , true);
$image->borderImage('white', ($image->getImageWidth() - $desired_width) / 2,($image->getImageHeight() - $desired_height ) / 2);

and you must completely hate me by now :(

Comment: This is getting substantially beyond webmaster I g now and more into programming. Best bet go to stack overflow.